# Using a regex to check for special characters java

Tags: java, regex, string, concatenation

I want to check and see if a word contains a special character and remove it. Lets say I have `String word = "hello-there"`, I want to loop through and check to see if the word doesn't contain a letter, then remove that special character and concatenate the word. So I want to turn `hello-there` into `hellothere` using regex. I have tried this but I can't seem to figure out how to check individual characters of a string to a regex.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
String word = "hello-there";

for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
{
    if(word.charAt(i).matches("^[a-zA-Z]+"))
```

But the last if statement doesn't work. Anybody know how to take care of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following *regex*, that'll match any character, that is not a lower-case or upper-case letter.

```
[^a-zA-Z]+
```

see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0ljY3K/2)

**Java** ( [demo](https://ideone.com/sbK8pX) )

```
class RegEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "hello-there";
        String r = "[^a-zA-Z]+";
        String o = s.replaceAll(r, "");
        System.out.println(o); //-> hellothere
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! While I was waiting for an answer I found the replaceAll method and tried to work with it but couldn't figure out the regex that meant everything but a letter! Thank you!

Comment: Actually, that still doesn't remove most of the things I was looking for. Is there a way to check for anything that is not a lower or uppercase letter?

Comment: I tried it and it works! Although I think it is a-z on the first one not a-b. After changing it to a-z it worked!

Comment: @Programmer ya that's a typo :)

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Getting familiar with regex. Hard to understand but getting the hang of it. Thanks! XD